# Intersection of two subgroups with given information

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

suppose we know that $G$ is a finite group with order $43200$ and suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with order $80$. Furthermore, assume that $K$ is also a subgroup of $G$ such that $[G:K]=1600$.

**Claim: $H\cap K=\{e\}$**

I think one has to use Lagrange from this. One obtain that the order of $K$ has to be $27$ and that $[G:K]=540$. But how to get further. Do one to have argue by contradiction?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Lagrange is the way to go. Note that $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $K$, so its order must divide $|H|$ as well as $|K|$...